# Merge a list of separate JSON data into one piece of JSON data

Tags: python, json, pandas

In Python, I am trying to turn a list of separate JSON data:

```
[[{'id': 1, 'name': 'pencil', 'description': '2b or not 2b, that is the question'}], [{'id': 2, 'name': 'oil pastel', 'description': None}], [{'id': 3, 'name': 'gouache', 'description': None}], [{'id': 4, 'name': 'paper', 'description': None}]]
```

into one piece of JSON data:

```
{'id': 1, 'name': 'pencil', 'description': '2b or not 2b, that is the question'}, {'id': 2, 'name': 'oil pastel', 'description': None}, {'id': 3, 'name': 'gouache', 'description': None}, {'id': 4, 'name': 'paper', 'description': None}, {'id': 5, 'name': 'coloured pencil', 'description': None}
```

Been struggling with it for a few hours. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: normal [i[0] for i in data] will work i guess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use simple list-comprehension

```
[y for x in list_of_lists for y in x]
```

**Output:**

```
[{'description': '2b or not 2b, that is the question', 'id': 1, 'name': 'pencil'}, {'description': None, 'id': 2, 'name': 'oil pastel'}, {'description': None, 'id': 3, 'name': 'gouache'}, {'description': None, 'id': 4, 'name': 'paper'}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain)

```
>>> list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(j))
```

Or a list comprehension

```
>>> [x[0] for x in j] # Assuming there is only one item in each list
```

Both outputs

```
[{'id': 1,
  'name': 'pencil',
  'description': '2b or not 2b, that is the question'},
 {'id': 2, 'name': 'oil pastel', 'description': None},
 {'id': 3, 'name': 'gouache', 'description': None},
 {'id': 4, 'name': 'paper', 'description': None}]
```

Comment: >>> [x[0] for x in j] works great but do you have any advice for when there is more than one item in each list?

Comment: @user3217251 I was going to add the case for `n` items in the list, but Jay answered exactly that before I was finished editing, so I just erased it :) Take a look at this answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Using `functools` with `operator`

```
 j = [[{'id': 1, 'name': 'pencil', 'description': '2b or not 2b, that is the question'}], [{'id': 2, 'name': 'oil pastel', 'description': None}], [{'id': 3, 'name': 'gouache', 'description': None}], [{'id': 4, 'name': 'paper', 'description': None}]]


import functools
import operator
functools.reduce(operator.iadd,j,[])
```

Output:

```
[{'id': 1,
'name': 'pencil',
  'description': '2b or not 2b, that is the question'},
 {'id': 2, 'name': 'oil pastel', 'description': None},
 {'id': 3, 'name': 'gouache', 'description': None},
 {'id': 4, 'name': 'paper', 'description': None}]
```